# How to check list orders (further properties) with NUnit?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, nunit-3.0

I want NUnit tests a list order, based on two properties instead of one.

*Snippet code (working):*

```
var list = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
{
    new Tuple<string, string>("aaaa", "bbbb"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("bbbb", "aaaa"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("aaaa", "cccc"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("cccc", "bbbb")
};
var ordered = list.OrderBy(p => p.Item1).ThenBy(p => p.Item2);
Assert.That(ordered, Is.Ordered.By("Item1"));
```

*Snippet code (what I want - not working):*

```
var list = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
{
    new Tuple<string, string>("aaaa", "bbbb"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("bbbb", "aaaa"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("aaaa", "cccc"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("cccc", "bbbb")
};
var ordered = list.OrderBy(p => p.Item1).ThenBy(p => p.Item2);
Assert.That(ordered, Is.Ordered.By("Item1").ThenBy("Item2"));
// Below syntax works but does not return expected result
// Assert.That(ordered, Is.Ordered.By("Item1").By("Item2"));
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: .ThenBy("Item2") in "Assert.That(ordered, Is.Ordered.By("Item1").ThenBy("Item2"));"

Comment: Seems you have to write your own extension to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, you know that there is no `ThenBy` syntax element in NUnit, but were hoping for `By` to apply multiple times. Neither feature is available and the CollectionOrderedConstraint only supports a single property name. It wouldn't be terribly difficult to implement either approach in NUnit, so you should consider filing an issue to request that feature.

For now, it's not possible. You should consider the workaround of creating an expected list of Tuples in the correct order and using testing the two lists for equality.

Comment: Conversation continues [here](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/1553)

Answer (score 1):

As another option you could look at the shouldly framework and do something like below

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GivenAnUnorderListWhenCustomOrderExecutedThenItemsOrderbyItemOneThenByItemTwo()
    {
        var expectedOrder = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
        {
                    new Tuple<string, string>("aaaa", "bbbb"),
                    new Tuple<string, string>("aaaa", "cccc"),
                    new Tuple<string, string>("bbbb", "aaaa"),
                    new Tuple<string, string>("cccc", "bbbb")
        };

        var list = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
        {
                    new Tuple<string, string>("aaaa", "bbbb"),
                    new Tuple<string, string>("bbbb", "aaaa"),
                    new Tuple<string, string>("aaaa", "cccc"),
                    new Tuple<string, string>("cccc", "bbbb")
        };

        var orderedList = list.OrderBy(p => p.Item1).ThenBy(p => p.Item2);
        orderedList.ShouldBe(expectedOrder);
    }
```

Comment: In my real case, it's a SQL query. I transformed that into a Tuple for more simplicity. So expectedOrder using a SQL query is more difficult to test.